# How to create a Matlab array given another array

Tags: matlab

Let us assume a simple array `A`

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
```

I would like to create an array `B` that will contain the `A` as many as 2 times:

```
B = [A A]
```

Then `B`, will be of dimensions `(1,2*length(A))`

How can I do the same, but for `N` times (e.g. using a for loop or something like this)?

```
for i = 1:N
    B = ???
end
```

so that

```
B = [A A A.....A]
```

I tried `repmat` to make first the `B` as a matrix, and then `reshape`. However `reshape` does not work as I was expecting and instead of giving:

```
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     1     2     3     4     
5     6     7     8
```

it gave:

```
1     1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5     5     6     6     
7     7     8     8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep stacking them, like: `B = [B A]` inside the loop. Or even better, use the [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) `repmat()` which stacks them in a single function call.
In your case of row-major stacking:

```
n = 100; % for 100 reps
B = repmat(A,1,n)
```

Comment: Yep! I didn't think of using repmat in this specific way! Thanks